# why ami seeing this error pub get failed(65) Expected a key while parsing a block mapping

Tags: flutter

I can't add image assets in my app. it's showing

> Expected a key while parsing a block mapping

```
dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
flutter:
 assets:
  - images/app_logo.png
```

Comment: Please format your code so that it's easier to read it.

Comment: I think your YAML file might be formatted wrong, could you add it to the question so we can see.

Comment: The problem is solved. I removed the whitespace before asssets. Thank youu all for suggesting.

Answer (score 0):

I removed the whitespace before assets. And it works